# Twitter API POST in cordova/ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

So, I followed the instructions here:
http://blog.ionic.io/displaying-the-twitter-feed-within-your-ionic-app/

getHomeTimeline works fine, but when I try to add a new method to unfollow a user:

```
    unfollow: function(user_id) {
        var unfollow_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/destroy.json?user_id='+user_id;
        createTwitterSignature('POST', unfollow_url);
        return $resource(unfollow_url).query();
    }
```

I get:

> GET
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/destroy.json?user_id=807095
>   401 (Authorization Required)

createTwitterSignature method is unchanged as per the tutorial:

```
function createTwitterSignature(method, url) {
    var token = angular.fromJson(getStoredToken());
    var oauthObject = {
        oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
        oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
        oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
        oauth_version: "1.0"
    };
    var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url, oauthObject, {}, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
}
```

I checked out ngTwitter, but it changes my code too much and I feel like the issue is rather simple (*also doesn't include POST friendships/destroy*). It seems to be something related to Cordova that I found in different posts, but none of them really provide an answer besides using ngTwitter.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return $resource(unfollow_url).save()
```

I think that `$resource().query()` will do a `GET` and you need a `POST` for this API call